# Compare innerHTML of DomNode with Regex instead of "==="?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm playing around with Puppeteer and I find it great to learn more native JavaScript while doing it. One thing I couldn't find an explanation for was comparing the innerHTML of a DomNode to a given string.

If I use a RegEx it works:

```
await page.$$eval("span", async (spans) => {
        const term = "xxx";
        const reX = new RegExp(term);
        spans.forEach((span) => {
            console.log(reX.test(span.innerHTML));
        });
    });
```

If returns true (if the span is present).

If I do the same operation using the `===` operator I get `false` as an output. I'm not sure why that is.

```
await page.$$eval("span", async (spans) => {
        const term = "xxx";
        spans.forEach((span) => {
            console.log(term === span.innerHTML);
        });
    });
```

Can someone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: What is the HTML of the `<span>` that produces this behavior? (looking at that should make it pretty clear)

Comment: `<span>xxx</span>`

Comment: That should not produce the problem you describe.

Comment: Your regex tests if the string _contains_ that string while `===` checks if it matches the full string. Do you have any whitespace inside the `<span>` tags by any chance?

Comment: oh, yeah - that could be possible. Does `new Regex(...).test(...)` automatically apply the `/g` flag?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, these are not identical comparisons.

[`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is much different from [strict equality (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality).

This example might make it a bit more clear:

```js
const stringToCheck = "xxx";
console.log(/x/.test(stringToCheck)); // true
console.log("x" === stringToCheck);   // false
```

And that is because `/x/.test(stringToCheck)` simply looks for "x" anywhere in the string and it did find it, whereas `"x" === stringToCheck` would return true only if `stringToCheck` contains only one character "x".